# Set equal height of two independent angularjs components

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize, height, angular-components

I have two angularjs components displaying different content placed vertically parallel on a page -
[image: angularjs components]

I need to set the height of both components to be be equal. So, I need to increase the height of components B to be equal to height of component A if the height of component A is more than that of component B based on the content that component A is displaying.
Also, whenever the content/height of any of the component increases, I again need to re-adjust the height of other component.

I have tried getting the height of the components on ng-init using heightOffset but get the value as 0 consistently. I have also looked at ResizeObserver, but that has limited browser support at this time.

Any other way to achieve the required behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved purely with css. You can use a `flex-box` with `align-items: stretch;`. Look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 10px;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('left').innerHTML += 'New line<br>'">Add new line to left</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('right').innerHTML += 'New line<br>'">Add new line to right</button>
```

Comment: i had both the components with col-md-6. After applying the above CSS, the width of both the components is getting reduced. Any idea?

Comment: @SoftEngi try removing the  `flex-grow` part. or chang it to `flex-grow: 0;`

Comment: @SoftEngi Well without any code it is hard to tell where the problem ist. maybe you update your question with some code. Then i will see if i can help.

Comment: your suggestion worked correctly in a plnkr, though it was behaving as mentioned above